# Make callers use functools.partial or call a factory function?

Tags: python

I've read several arguments comparing `partial` vs `lambda`, but most of them talked about how `partial` is more flexible (not limited to expressions) and gives info about the wrapped function.  But I want to consider this from the caller's perspective.  Here's my situation.

I have a function that takes a 1-argument modifier function.  A request is passed into that modifier function to be modified:

```
def my_func(request, modifier):
  modifier(request)
```

I'm also building some utilities that makes it easier to create parameterized modifier functions, e.g. adding/modifying URL params to the request.  I thought of two ways of doing it, but not sure which one is better.

### Option 1

```
def add_params(request, params):
  for param in params:
    # Manipulate the request with param.
```

This way, callers can use `functools.partial` to bind the `params`, like this:

```
modifier = functools.partial(add_params, params={'abc':'123'})
```

### Option 2

```
def add_params(params):
  def func(request):
    for param in params:
      # Modify request with param.
  return func
```

Then callers use it like this:

```
modifier = add_params({'abc':'123'})
```

## Question

If I don't care about function introspection, are there any downsides to using option 2?  Would option 2 run into late binding issues? (Although my use case doesn't run into that).  I really like how option 2 is easier for callers to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two functions are completely isomorphic to each other from a mathematical perspective (though their efficiency may vary):

```
# Option 1
(Request, Params) -> None

# Option 2
Params -> (Request -> None)
```

For your purpose, I would say option 2 offers the most convenience since the function is already curried, so you can not only avoid `partial` but can also compose them easily:

```
import functools
def compose(*fs):
  return functools.reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x)), fs)

modifier = compose(add_params({'abc':'123'}),
                   add_params({'def':'456'}))
```

If you ever want to call the function directly you can always do:

```
add_params({'abc':'123'})(request)
```

which is not really all that involved compared to option 1:

```
add_params(request, {'abc':'123'})
```

Late binding shouldn't pose an issue unless you use variables from outside the function, and if you do there's always a way to work around it.

Unfortunately option 2 has the disadvantage of being annoying to define, but this can be simplified using decorators:

```
def curry_request(f):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    def inner(request):
      f(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return inner
  return wrapper

@curry_request
def add_params(request, params):
  # do something
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My priority is to make it easier for the caller to use these modifiers, so being a bit verbose in the definition is ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

Compared with partial function implementation code,your option 2 is also good,i don't think it has any downsides in your situation.But functools.partial is a common way to result in a simplified signature,
if you want to ruturn a new partial function for another function,you can still invoke partial func.if you want to use option 2 model,you may need to implement a new function

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the part about `partial` being more reusable.